# Дискретное логарифмирование

Tags: математика, криптография, дискретная-математика

Известно, что:

Дискретное логарифмирование это решение уравнения S=nT mod{m} относительно n (0 < n < m-1) при известных S и T.
Задача сводится к нахождению конкретной величины n.

Вопрос:
Как можно определить не конкретную величину  "n" а четность/нечетность или в каком сегменте значение находится  "n" ?
Существуют какие-то алгоритмы?

Comment: Это может выглядеть так. Критерии четности индекса: (-1)^n = 1 mod (m), n - четно, (-1)^n = -1 mod (m),  n - нечетно.